# Comments in ArrayList get messed up after deletion / removal of comment in list

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I have a comments feature in my app where users can comment on each other's posts and also they can either like or dislike each other's comments. Also, if they are discontent with their comment they can delete it. Everything works fine until I get to the deletion of the comments part because then I call `notifyDataSetChanged();` or `notifyItemRangeChanged();` and everything gets messed up, because when the list of comments refreshes and I try to like some comment in the list, sometimes more than one gets liked, or if I click dislike, sometimes more than one gets disliked, and sometimes both like and dislike end up selected.

[image]

I have literally tried a thousand ways to fix it and nothing has worked. Below I will show you guys some examples of things I have tried... In the onChildRemoved(); I have tried it like this:

**CommentsActivity**

```
private void readComments() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(mPostId);
        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                comment.setComment(comment.getComment());
                mCommentList.add(comment);
                keysList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mCommentAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mCommentList.size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mCommentAdapter.removeComment(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCommentAdapter);
                mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        reference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
    }
```

```
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int index = keysList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                mCommentList.remove(index);
                mCommentAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
                keysList.remove(index);
                mCommentAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(index, mCommentList.size());
            }
```

```
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            index = keysList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            keysList.remove(index);
            mCommentList.remove(index);
            mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

And the list continues. I have tried so many variations of these and still after deleting a comment, when I try to like or dislike a comment in the list more than one gets like or disliked and sometimes both like and dislike end up selected.

Ideas on what might be causing this?

**CommentAdapter** (How I like & dislike comments)

```
public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Comment> mCommentList;

    private String mPostId;
    private String mNotificationId;

    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, List<Comment> mComment, String mPostId) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mCommentList = mComment;
        this.mPostId = mPostId;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);

        return new CommentAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final Comment comment = mCommentList.get(position);

        holder.comment.setText(comment.getComment());

        commentLike(comment.getCommentid(), holder.commentLike);
        commentDislike(comment.getCommentid(), holder.commentDislike);
        getUserInfo(holder.image_profile, holder.username, comment.getPublisher());
        commentLikesNumber(holder.commentLikesNumber, comment.getCommentid());
        commentDislikesNumber(holder.commentDislikesNumber, comment.getCommentid());
        commentResponseNumber(holder.commentResponseNumber, comment.getCommentid());

        holder.iconComment.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ResponseActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("commentid", comment.getCommentid());
            intent.putExtra("publisherid", comment.getPublisher());
            intent.putExtra("postid", mPostId);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        });

        holder.commentLike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like") && holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike")) {
                likeComment(comment.getCommentid(), mPostId, comment.getPublisher());
            } else if (holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like") && holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("disliked")) {
                likeComment(comment.getCommentid(), mPostId, comment.getPublisher());
                removeDislike(comment.getCommentid());
            } else {
                removeLike(comment.getPublisher(), comment.getCommentid());
            }
        });

        holder.commentDislike.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike") && holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("like")) {
                dislikeComment(comment.getCommentid());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Don't be mean", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (holder.commentDislike.getTag().equals("dislike") && holder.commentLike.getTag().equals("liked")) {
                dislikeComment(comment.getCommentid());
                removeLike(comment.getPublisher(), comment.getCommentid());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Don't be mean", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                removeDislike(comment.getCommentid());
            }
        });

        holder.image_profile.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("publisherid", comment.getPublisher());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        });

        //Timestamp to Date
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date date = new Date(timestamp.getTime());

        //Current timestamp
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long ts = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        //Getting comment timestamp from database
        long timestampOfComment = comment.getTimestamp();

        //SECOND WAY

        long duration = ts - timestampOfComment;

        long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
        long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
        long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
        long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);

        if (diffInSeconds < 10) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(" \u25CF " + "Just now");
        } else if (diffInSeconds > 10 && diffInSeconds < 60) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(" \u25CF " + diffInSeconds + " seconds ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds > 60 && diffInMinutes == 1) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(" \u25CF " + diffInMinutes + " minute ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds > 60 && diffInMinutes < 60) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(" \u25CF " + diffInMinutes + " minutes ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds > 60 && diffInMinutes > 60 && diffInHours == 1) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(" \u25CF " + diffInHours + " hour ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds > 60 && diffInMinutes > 60 && diffInHours > 1 && diffInHours < 24) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(" \u25CF " + diffInHours + " hours ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds > 60 && diffInMinutes > 60 && diffInHours > 24 && diffInDays == 1) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(" \u25CF " + diffInDays + " day ago");
        } else if (diffInSeconds > 60 && diffInMinutes > 60 && diffInHours > 24 && diffInDays > 1) {
            holder.timestamp.setText(" \u25CF " + diffInDays + " days ago");
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            if (comment.getPublisher().equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid())) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Would you like to delete this comment?");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "No", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                    deleteCommentNotification(mPostId, comment.getCommentid());
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments Liked").child(comment.getCommentid()).setValue(null);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments Disliked").child(comment.getCommentid()).setValue(null);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Responses").child(comment.getCommentid()).setValue(null);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your comment has been deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mCommentList != null) {
            return mCommentList.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CircleImageView image_profile;
        TextView username, comment, commentLikesNumber, commentDislikesNumber, commentResponseNumber, timestamp;
        ImageView commentLike, commentDislike, iconComment;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            commentLike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_thumb_up_grey);
            commentDislike = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_thumb_down_grey);
            commentLikesNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_likes_number);
            commentDislikesNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_dislikes_number);
            iconComment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_comment_grey);
            commentResponseNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_response_number);
            timestamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        }
    }

    private void deleteCommentNotification(String postid, String commentid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments").child(postid).child(commentid);
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String notificationId = dataSnapshot.child("notificationId").getValue(String.class);
                    String user = dataSnapshot.child("for").getValue(String.class);
                    if (notificationId != null && user != null) {
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(user).child(notificationId).removeValue();
                        reference.removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getUserInfo(final ImageView prof_image, final TextView username, String publisherid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(publisherid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user != null) {
                    Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(prof_image);
                    username.setText(user.getUsername());
                } else {
                    prof_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_placeholder);
                    username.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void removeComment(final String key) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mCommentList.size(); i++) {
            if (mCommentList.get(i).getCommentid().equals(key)) {
                mCommentList.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void commentLike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Liked").child(commentid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_blue);
                        imageView.setTag("liked");
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_grey);
                        imageView.setTag("like");
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void commentDislike(final String commentid, final ImageView imageView) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Disliked").child(commentid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mFirebaseUser != null)
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_blue);
                        imageView.setTag("disliked");
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_grey);
                        imageView.setTag("dislike");
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void commentLikesNumber(TextView commentLikesNumber, String commentid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Liked").child(commentid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long commentLikes = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                if (commentLikes == 0) {
                    commentLikesNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    commentLikesNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    commentLikesNumber.setText(String.valueOf(commentLikes));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void commentDislikesNumber(TextView commentDislikesNumber, String commentid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Disliked").child(commentid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long commentDislikes = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                if (commentDislikes == 0) {
                    commentDislikesNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    commentDislikesNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    commentDislikesNumber.setText(String.valueOf(commentDislikes));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void commentResponseNumber(TextView commentResponseNumber, String commentid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Responses").child(commentid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                long commentResponses = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                if (commentResponses == 0) {
                    commentResponseNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    commentResponseNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    commentResponseNumber.setText(String.valueOf(commentResponses));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void likeComment(String commentId, String postId, String userId) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments Liked").child(commentId).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());

        mNotificationId = reference.push().getKey();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);
        hashMap.put("commentid", commentId);
        hashMap.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.setValue(hashMap);

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap1.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap1.put("comment", "liked your comment");
        hashMap1.put("postid", postId);
        hashMap1.put("ispost", true);
        hashMap1.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);
        hashMap1.put("commentid", commentId);
        hashMap1.put("seen", false);
        hashMap1.put("type", "");

        if (!mFirebaseUser.getUid().equals(userId)) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userId).child(mNotificationId).setValue(hashMap1);
        }
    }

    private void removeLike(String userId, String commentId) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments Liked").child(commentId).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String notificationId = dataSnapshot.child("notificationId").getValue(String.class);
                    if (notificationId != null) {
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userId).child(notificationId).removeValue();
                        reference.removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void dislikeComment(String commentId) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments Disliked").child(commentId).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("commentid", commentId);
        hashMap.put("notificationId", mNotificationId);
        hashMap.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.setValue(hashMap);
    }

    private void removeDislike(String commentId) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments Disliked").child(commentId).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                reference.removeValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are liking and disliking post ? may be this funtionality is creating problem post code

Comment: @chandmohd in my Adapter class I like and dislike comments based on their tags. I just posted the code so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the weird behaviour are the `ValueEventListener` objects you register on each call of `onBindViewHolder`. The `onBindViewHolder` method is called every time a new item scrolls into view, or has its data changed. Since you never unregister the listeners they continue to update the views, even when they may already be bound to other items.

Don't register any listeners in `onBindViewHolder`. Setup the `ValueEventListener`s with your adapter and unregister them when the adapter is not used anymore. Within the listener call the notify methods of the adapter instead of updating views directly. Move the registration of the OnClickListeners into your ViewHolder and make them generic, so that they are not bound to a specific item. The `onBindViewHolder` should simply update your view.

All the changes should fix your problem and make scrolling even smoother ;-)

**CommentAdapter**

```
public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Comment> mCommentList;

private String mPostId;
private String mNotificationId;

private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, List<Item> items, String mPostId) {
  this.items = items;
  this.mPostId = mPostId;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);
  return new CommentAdapter.ViewHolder(mContext, mPostId, view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

  holder.update(items.get(position));
  
}
```

**ViewHolder**

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private Item item;

public ViewHolder(Context context, String mPostId, View itemView) {  
        super(itemView);  
        
        // ...
    
        // Register OnClickListeners here once for the view. Example:
        icon.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        
          if (item != null) {
              Comment comment = item.getComment();
              Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ResponseActivity.class);
              intent.putExtra("commentid", comment.getCommentid());
              intent.putExtra("publisherid", comment.getPublisher());
              intent.putExtra("postid", mPostId);
              mContext.startActivity(intent);
          }
        });
        
       // ...
    }

public void update(Item item) {
    this.item = item;
    update(item.getComment());
    update(item.getLikeStatus());
}

public void update(Comment comment) {
    textControl.setText(comment.getText());
    // ...
}

public void update(LikeStatus status) {
    
    if (status.likes == 0) {
      likeNumbersText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      likeNumbersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      likeNumbersText.setText(String.valueOf(likes));
    }
    
    if (status.dislikes == 0) {
      dislikeNumbersText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      dislikeNumbersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      dislikesNumbersText.setText(String.valueOf(likes));
    }
  }
    // ...
}
```

**Activity**

```
  DatabaseReference comments = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(mPostId);
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
   
    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
        Item item = getItemByCommentId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
        item.setComment(comment);
        
        mCommentAdatper.notifyItemChanged(comment.getPosition()); 
    }

    //...
  
};

comments.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);


DatabaseReference likes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments Liked");
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
   
    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        long likes = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        String commendId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        Item item = getItemByCommentId(commendId);
        Comment comment = item.getComment();
        LikeStatus likeStatus = item.getLikeStatus();
        likeStatus.likes = likes;
      
        mCommentAdatper.notifyItemChanged(comment.getPosition());  
    }
    
    // ...
  
};

likes.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your response. I am trying to understand how to do what you are telling me to do. Can you give me an example of how to do it with one of my methods that's incorrectly placed? So for example, ```holder.commentLike(...)``` should be placed elsewhere to make the view more generic? And after it's called, remove the listener...?

Comment: Can you also share the code of likeComment and dislikeComment? Would it make easier to provide you an example.

Comment: Yeah man, absolutely. But are you thinking that I am writing the ```commentLike();``` and ```commentDislike();``` method in the ```Viewholder```? Because if so that's not the case. I just didn't want to overload the question with unnecessary code. Let me go ahead and upload my ```CommentAdapter``` class, so you can see it or maybe we could even chat and I'll send it to you that way. Whatever you prefer.

Comment: I've added some sample code to my answer. Tried to keep it simple and threfore left out some parts. Main point is that you have to use the Adapter in a different way and get the listeners out of the it.

Comment: In CommentAdapter in the constructor ```public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, List<Item> items, String mPostId)``` what's Item that you pass for the List? That's supposed to be my bean class, right? So, comment... I think

Comment: I keep getting some ```ClipDataItem``` whenever I try to pass Item to ```List<>```...

Comment: Item is just a custom class you have to declare.

Comment: Okay, so I'm trying to model your example and it's kind of a mess. You mind if we chat? I'm sure I'll be able to understand better and get things done quicker if we chat... Is that possible? I redid everything, but not sure how to handle the ```timestamp``` and some other stuff... The ```ViewHolder``` is what's throwing me off.